# Multiple related fields angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an angular 2 application where I need to have (apart from others), these 4 fields:

Gross Amount, Discount, Discount Percent and Net Amount.
The formula is:

Net Amount=Gross Amount-Discount

(and if Discount Percent is supplied , it should calculate Discount and use in above formula).

Is there a way so that I can have these 4 things depend on each other and change if one of them changes according to the formula?

Comment: you can use ngIf

Comment: @BhojendraNepal how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write something like this :

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
        Gross: <input type='text'   [(ngModel)]="grossAmount">
        Discount Percent  <input type='text' [(ngModel)]="discountPercent" (change)="calculateNet()">
        Discount:  {{discount}} 
         Net Amount: {{netAmount}}
         `
})
export class AppComponent {
  grossAmount = 0;
  discount = 0;
  discountPercent=0;
  netAmount=0;

 calculateNet(){
   if (this.discountPercent > 0){
     this.discount = this.grossAmount*this.discountPercent/100;
     this.netAmount = this.grossAmount - this.discount;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. I ended up using change event handlers on input tags all the 4 properties.(also surrounding the input tags in a div with a singler change event handler works fine)